# let numInArray: number[ ] = [ ]; Gives this ERROR " SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':' "

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am trying to automatically fill an empty array with numbers from 1 to 100 and then give the output if the following conditions are true:

1. Print number if it is not divisible by 3 and 5.
2. If number is divisible by 3 then print Fizz.
3. If number is divisible by 5 then print Buzz.
4. If number is divisible by both 3 and 5 then print FizzBuzz.

```
let num: number | string [] = [];

for (let i=1; i<=100; i++){
    if ( i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 !== 0 ) {
        num.push("Fizz");
    } if ( i % 3 !== 0 && i % 5 == 0 ){
        num.push("Buzz");
    }  if ( i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0 ){
        num.push("FizzBuzz");
    } if ( i % 3 !== 0 && i % 5 !== 0 ) {
        num.push(i);
    }
}

console.log(num);
```

I have run the same code in **JavaScript** without declaring type of num (**i.e, num: number | string []**) and the code is running fine but when I am running it in **TypeScript** it is giving the following error.

```
└─$ node test.ts 
/home/ahmed/Tutorials/JavaScript/test.ts:1
let num: number | string [] = [];
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:360:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1088:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1123:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47

Node.js v18.12.1
```

Comment: "*I am running it in TypeScript*" are you? How exactly do you execute this? Because it seems it's *not* processed as TS but as JS.

Comment: Ii order to run `*.ts` files in node js you need to use `node-ts` package , see here https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node

Comment: By default, Node.js doesn't know about TypeScript, so `node test.ts` will run `test.ts` as though it were a JavaScript file, and of coruse the `:` is indeed invalid at that position. You have to use a tool (like the TypeScript compiler, esbuild, various others) to convert the TypeScript to JavaScript and run the result. (You might also look into `ts-node`, which does the compilation on-the-fly.)

Comment: One additional thing to point out that makes it evident this is not processed as TS is that `let num: number | string []` is *either* an array of strings *or* a single number. Yet you do not seem to have a compilation error for `num.push(i);` which will attempt to add a number to what cannot be an array of numbers. [See the error on the TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mxa2BW)

Comment: Re `let num: number | string[]`, you probably meant `let num: (number | string)[]` or `let num: Array<number | string>` (which is the same thing written a second way). That makes `num` an array of things that can be either numbers or strings (rather than either a number or an array of strings).

Comment: Unrelated but did you know `if ( i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0 )` is equal to `if(i % 15 == 0)` ;3

Comment: `let num: number[] | string [] = [];` this should resolve  it

Comment: @CoderApprentice 
I tried both of these but it is giving the following error:
" The body of an 'if' statement cannot be the empty statement. "
" if(i % 15 == 0) ;3 { something } " and " if((i % 15 == 0) ;3) { something } "

Comment: @AhmedHassan There's a small misunderstanding haha, I meant ";3" as a catface smiley, it's not part of the code :) I just meant, for any number `i` where it is true that `i % 3 == 0` and `i % 5 == 0`, then that is equivalent to simply `i % 15 == 0`. It's a small efficiency improvement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run the typescript file you need to run the below command and then it will generate a javascript file and you can run that js file.

```
tsc test.ts
```